# KeyListeners or KeyBindings?

Tags: java, swing, key-bindings, keylistener

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [KeyListeners vs Keybindings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10035980/keylisteners-vs-keybindings)

I have a java program where I can move an ellipse using the a-s-d-w keys and also the arrow keys.

Should I use a keyListener in this example or should I use keyBindings? and why?

(Should I use a keyListener to catch all eight keys or use eight separate keyBindings?)