# How to add a single key shortcut to a JMenuItem

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts

I am creating a simple text editor similiar to Notepad.
It would insert the time and date to the file if the user presses <kbd>F5</kbd>.
I browsed about mnemonics and accelerators but they are used in combination with <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> respectively.

Should I use an `EventListener` or is there any other solution?

Comment: am having a problem when using this on a `JMenuItem` in a `JPopupMenu` it wont work unless i press on the `JPopupMenu` and the dropdown of options appears and then while its shown it will work how can i go make the shortcut work without the need to press and show scenario

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could simply use:

```
JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem("Refresh");
KeyStroke f5 = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F5, 0);
menuItem.setAccelerator(f5);
```

with KeyStroke having `0` specifying no modifiers as described in the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28int,%20int%29).

An ActionListener is the appropriate listener for menu item events.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that putting 0 as the 2nd argument to getKeyStroke meant the absence of modifiers

Comment: the accelerator definitely is an improvement (and got you my temporary upvote :-) but not the best possible (which is why I reverted the upvote). The best is to use an Action, set the accelerator property there and configure the menuItem with that action. And no, actionListeners are not appropriate for menu items (nor for other action-aware components): their show-stopper lack is that they don't have enablement support.

Answer (score 5):

As partly already mentioned in some comments, the recommended approach is

- use an action to configure a menuItem
- configure the action with an accelerator
- add the action to the menu

Some code:

```
Action doLog = new AbstractAction("Dummny log!") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        LOG.info("doing: " + getValue(Action.NAME));
    }
};
doLog.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F5"));

JMenu menu = new JMenu("dummy");
menu.add(doLog);
frame.getJMenuBar().add(menu);
```

Comment: Can you put in some links where this is the recommended approach? I always work with listeners and am curious why this is not the way to do it. Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `KeyBinding` to your `JMenuItem` like this:

```
Action sayHello = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Hello World, From JMenuItem :)");
    }
};
jMenuItem.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("F5"),"sayHello");//4.The WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW input maps of all the enabled components in the focused window are searched.
jMenuItem.getActionMap().put("sayHello",sayHello);
```

**References:**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#getInputMap(int)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html#howto

Comment: Thanks but how is this different from using a key listener?

Comment: @NiceBooks see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664250/comparing-functionality-between-keylisteners-and-key-bindings

Comment: Thanks, that link explained it

Comment: generally a good technique ... but not for menuItems: they alread have an action attached to them and typically the requirement is to trigger that action with the keystroke from anywhere in the application (at least its containing window) - your binding will not work because it's registered with the when-focused inputMap (which a menuItem rarely is). For that use-case, the Action has special api, look for accelerator :-)

Comment: @kleopatra yes that is true. But by setting the `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` this should allow the above to work or am I wrong again :?

Comment: it might work - but still by-passing the design: JMenuItems are action-aware, so use the in-built support instead of re-inventing the wheel :-)

Comment: @kleopatra I tested the code and it works. As for re-inventing the wheel I think not, `getInputMap()` by default uses `WHEN_FOCUSED` you can explicly set it like `getInputMap(int JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)` the docs state this too. But difference in opinions I guess

Comment: not talking about the inputMap - talking about Actions and their support for accelerators used by JMenuItems: setting an action configured with the keyStroke as the item's action is the highest abstraction available and as such should be used instead of manually fiddling with action/inputMaps ... my downvote sticks ;-)