# KeyListener vs. Key Bindings

Tags: java, swing, awt, keylistener, key-bindings

People here keep suggesting to me to use Key Binding instead of `KeyListener` in Java 2D games.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each one? Is Key Bindings really better for 2D games?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing functionality between KeyListeners and Key Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664250/comparing-functionality-between-keylisteners-and-key-bindings)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Key bindings vs. key listeners in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290035/key-bindings-vs-key-listeners-in-java)

Answer (score 9):

`KeyListener` is a much lower level API which requires the component that it is registered to be focused AND have keyboard focus.  This can cause issues when you have other components within your game that may grab keyboard focus, for example.

`KeyListener` is generally more difficult to maintain and extend or change, as typically, all the key events are channelled through a single listener, so ALL the game controls originate from this single position.

(Now imagine you want to add other controls, such as buttons or even joystick or controllers to mix - you suddenly have any number of input hubs you need to consider, keep up to date and in sync :P)

The Key Bindings API has been designed to provide re-usable `Action`s which can be used in a variety of different parts of the Swing API, while this makes desktop application development easier, it can also make it easier when developing games...

Apart from the fact that you now gain control over the focus level that the events are generated, you also gain the flexibility to defining configurable key's which can be mapped to different actions

For example...

You define an `Up` `Action`, which moves you character up.  This is divorced from any event.  That means, the `Action` does not care how it is triggered, only what it should do when it is triggered.

You are now free to define the keystroke which would trigger this action.  The great part about this, is suddenly have the ability to provide customisation to the user, so they can actually define the key stroke they want for the action - for example, without having to design some kind of key mapping system of your own.

It also means that you can use the same `Action` (and even the same instance) in a variety of different ways.  For example, you can bind the `Action` to a key stroke and add it to button and if you're brave enough to try, even bind it another input device (like a joystick or controller)...but you'd need to build the API yourself to achieve it, but it means you suddenly have a single API concept for all your user input, for example...

Answer (score 0):

Key bindings were introduced later. They map actions to specific keys whereas a listener simply listens for which keys are pressed. To be honest, it doesn't really matter which one you use, but it's always preferable to use key bindings.

There are many libraries also available which have their advantages/disadvantages. Key bindings should be fine though for a 2D game. However, please note that using the Java API is not recommended for game development. If you ever want to build 3D, or content rich 2D games, it's much better to use OpenGL. Try LWJGL or JOGL (LWJGL is preferred generally) or you can use a game engine such as Slick2D or LibGDX.

Comment: Do the 3D (or even 2D) engines provide input APIs or are the just focused on output?

Comment: @MadProgrammer The ones that I know about have their own input APIs since OpenGL is typically tied to a native viewport. The only way to capture input is in native so a JNI-based library will have to provide their own API for a user to program it in Java.